# Preventing memory leaks in polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, polymorphism

In the following exercise I have created a polymorphic relationship between a base class and several derived classes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Panthera
{
public:
    virtual void roar() = 0;
    virtual ~Panthera() {}
};

class Lion : public Panthera
{
public:
    void roar() { cout << "roaring like a lion... " << endl; }
};

class Tiger : public Panthera
{
public:
    void roar() { cout << "roaring like a tiger..." << endl; }
};

class Jaguar : public Panthera
{
public:
    void roar() { cout << "roaring like a jaguar... " << endl; }
};

class Leopard : public Panthera
{
public:
    void roar() { cout << "roaring like a leopard... " << endl; }
};

void speak(Panthera *object)
{
    object->roar();

    delete object; // this is meant to prevent memory leak

    cout << "deleting pointer... " << endl;
}

int main()
{

    Lion lion;
    Tiger tiger;
    Jaguar jaguar;
    Leopard leopard;

    speak(&lion);
    speak(&tiger);
    speak(&jaguar);
    speak(&leopard);

    cout << "program ending... " << endl;

}
```

I have set the base class destructor to virtual and deleted the pointer in the function "speak" to prevent memory leaks, and while the code does compile and run without any warnings or errors, I get the following results from a memory leak detector:

```
Error #1: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT to free 0x0028ff2c
# 0 replace_free               [d:\drmemory_package\com...
# 1 Lion::~Lion                [../src/bigCats.cpp:11]
# 2 speak                      [../src/bigCats.cpp:39]
# 3 main                       [../src/bigCats.cpp:52]
Note: @0:00:01.466 in thread 7936

Error #2: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT to free 0x0028ff28
# 0 replace_free                [d:\drmemory_package\com...
# 1 Tiger::~Tiger               [../src/bigCats.cpp:17]
# 2 speak                       [../src/bigCats.cpp:39]
# 3 main                        [../src/bigCats.cpp:53]
Note: @0:00:01.482 in thread 7936

Error #3: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT to free 0x0028ff24
# 0 replace_free                  [d:\drmemory_package\com...
# 1 Jaguar::~Jaguar               [../src/bigCats.cpp:23]
# 2 speak                         [../src/bigCats.cpp:39]
# 3 main                          [../src/bigCats.cpp:54]
Note: @0:00:01.497 in thread 7936

Error #4: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT to free 0x0028ff20
# 0 replace_free                    [d:\drmemory_package\com...
# 1 Leopard::~Leopard               [../src/bigCats.cpp:29]
# 2 speak                           [../src/bigCats.cpp:39]
# 3 main                            [../src/bigCats.cpp:55]
Note: @0:00:01.529 in thread 7936
```

I also noted that the program has crashed occasionally at random intervals, although it does seem to work most of the time. Curiously when I get rid of the "delete object" command in the "speak" function, these errors from the memory leak detector completely disappear.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here? My textbook understanding tells me that I need to delete the pointer to the base class to prevent memory errors and avoid unpredictable program behavior, but I seem to be experiencing the complete opposite.

Comment: Only `delete` pointers obtained through `new`. Your objects are on the stack, so you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you must carefully manage all objects lifetime.

`delete x` is only valid on a pointer to an objeft created by `new`.

You created objects in automatic storage.  There is no need to `delete` to prevent memory leaks, and doing so is undefined behaviour.

Avoid using raw pointers that "own" resources; use `unique_ptr` instead when you must heap allocate.  Avoid heap allocation; learn the rule of 5, and only heap allocate when required.

Comment: So when is it actually useful to allocate memory dynamically? Especially inside of a class, instead of just being passed through a function. I know this might seem like a stupid question because there are a million tutorials that answer this question to an extent, but I feel like I am just not grasping what a pointer is capable of doing that cannot be done by reference.

Comment: Heap allocation is useful for several situations: 1. You don't know the object's size at compile time. This is the case for arrays, if you get required size during run time only, e. g. user input. If you now are told to prefer `std::vector` instead (yes, do so!), then you still have heap allocation, it is just hidden away from you by the container...  2. Lifetime of the object is longer than the scope it is created in. Then you have two options: return by value, using copy or move semantics - or create it on the heap, passing around pointers. 3. The object created is too large for the stack...

Comment: Thank you for this explanation... never considered that some of these problems could be solved with pointers

Answer (score 0):

From [class.dtor#12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.dtor#12)

> A destructor is also invoked implicitly through use of a
>   delete-expression for a constructed object **allocated** by a
>   *new-expression*;

Thus, only use `delete` operator when you allocate objects using `new` operator.

Lifetime of an object - The object not allocated by `new` will be destructed automatically as soon as it goes out of scope (which in your case, when it goes out of main's block scope).